# ABP.IO - Modify tenant onboard flow by customizing Tenant Management Module UI and API

Tags: stripe-payments, multi-tenant, abp

We own the commercial license of ABP and using the built in [Tenant Management Module](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Modules/Tenant-Management#tenant-management-module) with Angular UI.

We need to accomplish the following customization while onboarding a new tenant

1. Display existing & extra properties of **Identity** module in create/edit tenant page.

   - we are not sure how to display the existing or extra properties of the Identity module while creating the tenant. Along with Tenant admin's email address, Tenant admin's password, we need to get the Phone Number (available in Identity module) and Country (new extra property added in Identity Module). How to achieve this?
     [image]
2. Customize the tenant onboarding flow

   - As per the requirement, the end user will enter the Tenant and Tenant admin details and click on payment button. For payment, the user has to be redirected to stripe payment gateway. Upon successful payment, the tenant has to be created in database. Any idea on how to add this customization as part of onboarding flow?